# How to do async sqlalchemy db setup/teardown for unit tests

Tags: sqlalchemy, python-unittest

I'm trying to write some integration tests for a FastAPI app, but I'm running into issues with database synchronicity. My tests all pass when run individually, but running them all together, I get this error:

```
Error: (sqlalchemy.dialects.postgresql.asyncpg.InterfaceError) <class 'asyncpg.exceptions._base.InterfaceError'>: cannot perform operation: another operation is in progress
...
line 47, in asyncSetUp
    await connection.execute(table.delete())
```

My test base class has the setup/teardown code that is causing this issue (I know this is the issue because commenting out the db setup/teardown prevents the tests from crashing, but they all fail because they expect a fresh db state at the start of every test).

```py
class BaseTestCase(unittest.IsolatedAsyncioTestCase):

    async def asyncSetUp(self) -> None:
        await super().asyncSetUp()

        # reset db
        async with (await get_engine()).begin() as connection:
            # orm.Base is subclass of sqlalchemy.orm.DeclaritiveBase
            for table in reversed(orm.Base.metadata.sorted_tables):
                await connection.execute(table.delete())

        self.httpclient = AsyncClient(app=my_fastapi_app, base_url="http://test.com")

    async def asyncTearDown(self) -> None:
        await super().asyncTearDown()
        mockito.verifyStubbedInvocationsAreUsed()
        mockito.unstub()
        await self.httpclient.aclose()


# ...
async def get_engine() -> AsyncEngine:
    global _engine

    if _engine is not None:
        return _engine

    if app_config.db_connection_string is not None:
        db_uri = sqlalchemy.make_url(app_config.db_connection_string)
    else:
        assert app_config.db_driver is not None

        db_user = app_config.db_user
        db_pass = app_config.db_pass

        db_uri = sqlalchemy.engine.url.URL.create(
            drivername=app_config.db_driver,
            host=app_config.db_host,
            port=app_config.db_port,
            username=db_user,
            password=db_pass,
            database=app_config.db_name,
        )

    _engine = create_async_engine(db_uri, echo=True)
    return _engine
```

I'm pretty new to asyncio and sqlalchemy so I'm pretty lost on what I need to do in order to prevent my db setup/teardown code from conflicting. Maybe I'm not closing the engine/connection correctly? How can I fix this error? (I'm using postgres btw in case that matters)

Comment: I just decided to redo the whole thing from scratch since I couldn't find the issue and it seems to be working now. Still not sure whatever subtle bug was in the code